# Laravel 5.6 - A shared name for route resources

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

While creating an admin menu, i was wondering how to set active class item. The menu item have to stay active if the controller is showing, editing or doing something else.

sidebar.blade.php

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link {{ (Route::current()->getName() == 'posts' ? 'active' : '') }}" href="/admin/posts">Posts</a>
</li>
```

routes/web.php

```
// POSTS
Route::resource('/admin/posts', 'Admin\PostController');
```

How to set a shared name for all resources (index, create, show, etc.)?

I was hoping to do something like this but...

```
Route::resource('/admin/posts', 'Admin\PostController')->name('posts');
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `@if(Route::is('posts')) active @endif` as shorthand for your check above. It also supports wildcards: `@if(Route::is('admin.*')) active @endif`, which will match all routes starting with an `admin.` prefix.

Comment: @Namoshek exellent! that's exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

**Naming Resource Routes**

> By default, all resource controller actions have a route name; however, you can override these names by passing a names array with your options:

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->names([
    'create' => 'photos.build'
]);
```

You can find more options in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes).

Comment: They should be unique names per route, but having a common prefix to group them.

Answer (score 0):

work in laravel 9 try in other version

```
Route::resource('vente', VenteController::class,
['names'=>['index'=>'vente.index']]);
```

call it in menu

```
 <a href="{{route('vente.index')}}">vente</a>
```